# Using MaterliazeCSS and trying have a button in a fixed position inside it's parent element but having trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

So I'm working on a silly to do list app using mostly materialize and jquery.

Here is my codepen:

```
http://codepen.io/centraleft/pen/adWvPp
```

Basically the user enters text, my javascript takes that text and makes a new list element with a button inside of it. I want the button to always be on the far right of the list item regardless of the text inside the list element, so I float the button to the right however I run into a problem where I have an ugly little black sliver at the bottom of my list! Use the app once and you will see.

Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or a way to get rid of that black sliver with CSS?

Here is my current CSS for the button:

```
.orange {
  bottom: 7px;
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `button` is bleeding outside of your list. Set your `li`s to have a max height and overflow: hidden. See my [fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEWaXe).

The additions (CSS):

```
.collection-item {
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Ah! You're my hero! Honestly CSS is my weakest component in HTML5, there are a lot of properties that are unknown to me or that I don't understand very well. Do you have any tips for resources or ways to get a better grasp of vanilla CSS?

Comment: Like all things worth learning, it takes time. You are on a good path to mastering it!